# Is there a way to restore a database without killing the selects in execution?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a scheduled restore of 30 in 30 minutes on the server, but I use some databases from this server to get data for report, then when I have a heavy query, can the restoring process kill my query execution? Is there a way to make the restore wait the query finish?

Comment: *"Is there a way to restore a database without killing the selects in execution?"* No, there is no "online" restore. When a database is restored, it is put into the restoring state, and other logins cannot access it during that time.

Comment: If there are processes running, SQL Server will attempt to gain single user access, but it will not force those existing connections close unless you specifically state so. If there are connections, it will wait for all those connection to close (and any new ones that are opened to close). if they do no close in a timely manner, the restore will fail. If you state you want those connections closed, SQL Server will close the immediately.

Comment: Looks to me like you would need to use snapshots instead scheduled restores. I have not tested, but they are supposed to be faster to revert the database to the original state.

Comment: BTW reverting a snapshot would also require getting the database in single-user mode, no other connections allowed until reverted [reverting snapshots documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/revert-a-database-to-a-database-snapshot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: you should look into availability groups and read only replicas to keep your reporting database online and updated

Comment: I think its better to treat it in backend ... Setting a try/catch and a while loop to verify if the query will be interrupted, if it is true, then try again